# Map Target object with no source object using MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

I want to map a `Target` object with no source object using MapStruct. I tried it, but getting the below  error.

> Can't generate mapping method with no input arguments

Mapper code

```
public interface MyMapper {
@Mapping(target="student.courseName", constant="Master in Science")
Target map();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see this is not supported. And why would you do that? Why not just write your own method?

That aside, you can theoretically try passing a dummy parameter that won't be mapped.

```
public interface MyMapper {
    @Mapping(target="student.courseName", constant="Master in Science")
    Target map(Integer dummy);
}
```

Comment: Updated. But it should not have made a di

Comment: What if the target is not a string but a List<String> or any other type, the constant attribute supports only string types.